# Sort user locations iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I've an `NSArray` containing users information of their places, i.e their latitude and longitudes.
I also got the current user's location, now I want to sort out the list of latitudes and longitudes from the `NSArray` so that the current user can see his nearby users easily.

For instance, I've the following information.

```
NSArray *ALLINFOLAT = [ALLINFO valueForKey:@"lat"] 
// having "40.880048", "40.749315", "40.749278",
NSArray *ALLINFOLNG = [ALLINFO valueForKey:@"lng"] 
// having  "-77.145461", "-122.258591", "-122.320566"

NSString *currentUserLat = @"78";
NSString *currentUserLng = @"87";
```

How can I sort out the `NSDictionary ALLINFO` according to `currentUserLat` & `currentUserLng` using `NSSortDescriptor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing people by creating separate arrays for latitude and longitude.

If I understand correctly, you have an array ALLINFO that hold informations about users and their location, and you want to sort it based on distance to the current location.

You didn't specified what objects you have in array, so I assume they are dictionaries.

Here's how you get a sorted array:

```
CLLocation *currentLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude: 78 longitude: 87];

NSArray *orderedInfo = [ALLINFO sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(NSDictionary *object1, NSDictionary *object2)
{
    CLLocation *location1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude: [object1[@"lat"] doubleValue] longitude: [object1[@"lng"] doubleValue]];
    CLLocation *location2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude: [object2[@"lat"] doubleValue] longitude: [object2[@"lng"] doubleValue]];

    CLLocationDistance dist1 = [location1 distanceFromLocation:currentLocation];
    CLLocationDistance dist2 = [location2 distanceFromLocation:currentLocation];

    if (dist1 < dist2) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if ( dist1 > dist2) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    } else {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
    }
}];
```

Comment: What are the location1 and location2, where I've only current lat and lng and a list of lats and lngs.

Comment: They are just some temporary variables needed for sorting.

Comment: Can you show what kind of objects you have in ALLINFO array?

Comment: ALLINFO is an NSARRAY, which had `[ALLINFO valueForKey:@"lat"]` for latitude and  `[ALLINFO valueForKey:@"lng"]` for longitude

Comment: If ALLINFO is an NSARRAY then it contains objects that can be accessed by index and not by key. I believe your array contains NSDictionary. And when you call this [ALLINFO valueForKey:@"lat"] on an array, it actually forwards the call to all is dictionary objects and returns a new array with only the lat values extracted.

Comment: Ok. That means that my guesses were right, and the code above should work for you. Another thing, what do you mean sort out based on location? Do you want a new array with all your objects sorted based on distance to current location, or just some of the objects that are closer than 50km of your location for example?

Comment: based on the current location of user

Comment: I;ve the suer's current location double lat, lng and [Allinfo valueForKey:@"lat"] for latitudes and [Allinfo valueForKey:@"lng"] for lonigtudes.

Comment: I'm confusing between location1 and location2 and dist1 and dist2

Comment: As I said before you shouldn't care about "location1 and location2 and dist1 and dist2". They are just some variable that I used for sorting. They are not saved anywhere.  
Just try to use the code in the answer and you should have in the orderedInfo all the objects from your initial ALLINFO array but sorted by distance.

Comment: Yeah u r correct, but plz edit your and convert `lat's` and `lng's` as `[object1[@"lat"] doubleValue]`. I voted up just for your good understanding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75911/discussion-between-developer-and-pteofil).

Comment: If ALLINFO is NSDictionary so how can we can use **sortedArrayUsingComparator:** method with ALLINFO

Comment: ALLINFO is an NSArray that contains NSDictionary objects

Comment: No, See his question carefully ,NSArray *ALLINFOLAT = [ALLINFO valueForKey:@"lat"] 
NSArray *ALLINFOLNG = [ALLINFO valueForKey:@"lng"]

Comment: ALLINFO is not NSArray its NSDictionary, that's why he could use **valueForKey** method.

Comment: I already explained how this is possible in one of my first comments: "And when you call this [ALLINFO valueForKey:@"lat"] on an array, it actually forwards the call to all is dictionary objects and returns a new array with only the lat values extracted"

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *ALLINFOLAT =@[@(40.880048), @(40.749315), @(40.749278)];
NSMutableArray *ALLINFOLNG =@[@(-77.145461), @(-122.258591), @(-122.320566)];
NSString *currentUserLat = @"78";
NSString *currentUserLng = @"87";
CLLocation* currentLocation =[[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:[currentUserLat doubleValue] longitude:[currentUserLng doubleValue]];
NSMutableArray* locationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:[ALLINFOLNG count]];
for (int i=0; i<[ALLINFOLAT count]; i++) {
     CLLocationDegrees latValue = [ALLINFOLAT[i] doubleValue];
     CLLocationDegrees longValue = [ALLINFOLNG[i] doubleValue];
     CLLocation* location = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:latValue longitude:longValue];
     [locationArray addObject:location];   
}
NSArray* sortLocationArry = [locationArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(CLLocation* location1, CLLocation* location2) {
            CLLocationDistance distA = [location1 distanceFromLocation:currentLocation];
            CLLocationDistance distB = [location2 distanceFromLocation:currentLocation];
            if (distA < distB) {
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
            } else if ( distA > distB) {
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
            } else {
                return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
            }
        }];
```

To get sorted latitude and longitude,

```
[ALLINFOLAT removeAllObjects];
[ALLINFOLNG removeAllObjects];
[sortLocationArry enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CLLocation* location, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
   [ALLINFOLAT addObject:@(location.coordinate.latitude)];
   [ALLINFOLNG addObject:@(location.coordinate.longitude)];
}];
```

Comment: for this clean solution, thumbs up

Comment: Plz add this also that how can I get back the coordinates? currently its giving location

Comment: its ok, no worries. I was awaiting for you. `sortLat` and `sortLong ` are undefined. Also, I've to sort in NSARRY ALLINFO

Comment: You can't modified ALLINFOLAT and ALLINFOLNG because it defied as NSArray not NSMutableArray. See again i gonna modified answer.

Comment: Try now, I modified definition of ALLINFOLAT and ALLINFOLNG also  I used **removeAllObjects** method to avoid memory leak.

Comment: And one more thing u said in ur comment that u have to sort in nsarray ALLINFO but look at your code it isn't nsarray its nsdictionary. That's why i modified ALLINFOLAT and ALLINFOLNG arrays .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75908/discussion-between-developer-and-bhavesh).

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code for the sort by the location long/lati.

```
    NSArray *orderedUsers = [users sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a,id b) {
         User *userA = (User *)a;
         User *userB = (User *)b;
         CLLocationDistance distanceA = [userA.location getDistanceFromLocation:myLocation];
         CLLocationDistance distanceB = [userB.location getDistanceFromLocation:myLocation];
         if (distanceA < distanceB) {
             return NSOrderedAscending
         } else if (distanceA > distanceB) {
             return NSOrderedDescending;
         } else {
             return NSOrderedSame;
         }
    }];
```

**--------EDITED--------**

Following code for just pass the value of your long/lati only.

```
NSArray *orderedUsers = [self.shopsArray sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(double aLong, double bLong,double aLati, double bLati)
{
    CLLocation *usersA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude: aLati longitude: bLati];
    CLLocation *usersB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude: aLong longitude: bLong];

    CLLocationDistance distA = [usersA distanceFromLocation:currentLocation];
    CLLocationDistance distB = [usersB distanceFromLocation:currentLocation];

    if (distA < distB) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if ( distA > distB) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    } else {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
    }
}];
```

May this help to you.

Comment: What are a and b? they are lat and long ? of waht ?

Comment: I only want to sort out lat and lng. I'vent other informations